# How to open appropriate application based on file type

Tags: android, file

I was trying to open files that are placed in a folder. The idea is to provide maximum type of office files + pdf that a downloaded app can open. So i downloaded 14 different samples of file type like .docx, .ppt, .pdf etc.
I have WPS office as application to run these. But the problem is that when i use the below code then directly file is opened in WPS office application. And if i change to `target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(open), "application/pdf");` then it show adobe reader and WPS office as option. Is there any way that i get best possible option to open the file without specifying specifically /pdf or /msword? such that i get possible app list according to input type.

```
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(open), "application/msword");
                target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or
                    // something
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please install proper document reader in your device to open this file",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to open applications using the extension of the file, without specifying the application/***.

```
 File file = new File(filePath);
    MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
    String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

    if (type == null)
        type = "*/*";

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);

    intent.setDataAndType(data, type);

    startActivity(intent);
```

This should get the extension and open the 'best possible' application

Comment: thanks @harvey_slash this code works fine for office type document but in case of .txt and .pdf all application are shown. like in case of .pdf only 2 options should have been there i.e. adobe reader and WPS office as these two app are only capable to open this.

Comment: have you tried clicking the other apps and seeing what happens?I think the type==null is being returned true. thats why it is happening

Comment: thanks @harvey_slash. I just removed `if(type== null)` and its now working exactly how i wanted it to be.